# workaround for getting a list to map to a value in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

Here is some reproducible code below:

```
dict = {}

car = 'car'

bike = [4,5,6]
```

The desired outcome is to get

```
{'car':[4,5,6]}
```

Is there anyway I can do this

Comment: Building a dictionary from other variables is a very basic thing in Python. Please read some tutorials, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Don't name your variable `dict`: it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/ Follow this website, its really good for python beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning list as value to dictionary.

```
 d = {}

car = 'car'

bike = [4,5,6]
d[car] = bike
print(d)
```

Comment: car must be a variable so how would i do that

Comment: you can assign variable  as a key to dictionary.

Comment: tutorial to learn about dictionary. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp